# spring websocket. message doesn't come to the topic

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

When a customer places an order, it goes to the admin and the admin confirms and sends it to the chef to cook.
I send `procutList` to the controller, it comes in, but when the controller sends it to the chef page. Chef connects to the topic, but the callback doesn't go any further than that

```
-------------
admin page
    stompAdminClient.send('/app/chef', {}, productList)
-------------
@Controller
@Data
@Slf4j
public class ChefWebSocketController {
@MessageMapping("/chef")
@SendTo("/my-topic")
public List<ProductData> receiveOrder(List<ProductData> order) {
    return order;
}
}
```

---

```
chef page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chef Orders</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.5.0/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stompClient = null;
    var productList = [];

    function connect() {
        console.log("Connecting to WebSocket...");
        disconnect();
        var socket = new SockJS('/chef');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            console.log("Connected to WebSocket");
            stompClient.subscribe('/my-topic', function(order) {
                var data = JSON.parse(order.body);
                console.log("прилетело"+ order.body);
                var newProductList = data.productList;
                productList = newProductList;
                displayProductList(productList);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        if(stompClient != null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
            console.log("Disconnected from WebSocket");
        }
    }

    function displayProductList(productList) {
        console.log("Displaying product list:", productList);
        var productListContainer = document.getElementById('product-list-container');

        productList.forEach(function(product) {
            console.log("Processing product:", product);
            var productElement = document.createElement('div');
            productElement.innerHTML = "<p>Продукт: " + product.productName + "</p>" +
                "<p>Цена: " + product.price + "</p>" +
                "<p>Количество: " + product.count + "</p>";

            productListContainer.appendChild(productElement);
        });
    }
    
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="connect()" onunload="disconnect()">
 <div>
   <h1>Chef Orders</h1>
  <div id="product-list-container">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

the message comes to the admin and he sends it to the chef's controller, but it does not reach the chef's page, although the chef is connected:

```
 Connecting to WebSocket...
 stomp.min.js:8 Opening Web Socket...
 stomp.min.js:8 Web Socket Opened...
 stomp.min.js:8 >>> CONNECT
 accept-version:1.1,1.0
 heart-beat:10000,10000

 <<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:chef@gmail.com

Connected to WebSocket

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/my-topic
```

I've tried everything but nothing works please help me.